# How to install Scala for Android in Eclipse

Tags: android, scala

I'm new to the Scala langauge, I don't know how to install Scala for Android in Eclipse.

Comment: If this the one you mean http://code.google.com/p/scalaforandroid/ ?

Comment: What problems are you facing? This question needs to be more descriptive to be useful.

Comment: please make sure is it descriptive??

Comment: Google is the first place u should try. Then you should investigate and only when u get stuck you should ask a specific question on stackoverflow. You seem to have gone the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `build.xml` from [Scala for Android](http://code.google.com/p/scalaforandroid/).

And you need code editing support to Eclipse for Android install the Scala-IDE plugin. You can get it from [here](http://scala-ide.org).